# Play Framework: How to Get the Hostname Where the Application in Running

Tags: playframework

I know `RequestHeader` provides the `host` property that returns the hostname where application is running... but I need this info in my business code. Is there a way to determine the hostname without a `RequestHeader`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` to do a reverse lookup on the local host address.

Keep in mind that using the `RequestHeader` may be your only option, if the application is proxied in any way and [virtual host](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/HTTPServer) support is expected.

Answer (score 7):

There are only two possible solutions to this problem. The first one you've already mentioned which is a RequestHeader. The second one is placing your hostname in the application.conf file.